# JavaFX - ListView Selection and Making Text Appear

Tags: java, listview, javafx

This is my first post and I'm still a beginner in Java. The purpose of this program is to create a menu with food items in it and be able to select the items using ListView (which is the variable **menu** in this case). When I select the food items in the ListView, they are supposed to appear on the right side of the screen showing the text of what is selected (i.e. if Hamburger and Hotdog are selected from ListView, Hamburger and Hotdog appear as text on the right side of the screen). I got some pictures to include too, using ImageView and those images appear just fine without a problem. **The problem is when I select from ListView, nothing appears because I'm not sure how to make it appear**... I've tried get the index and then setting the text like that, getting the items, etc... I'm just really lost at the moment. I'm just not sure why it's not working because in my head the plan works fine, I get the index and then set that index to the ListView, getting the strings, but it's just not working. What am I doing wrong, or how should I be thinking about solving this?

Edit:
When I try to add the text from this line:

```
vBox.getChildren().add(foodItemsList[i]);
```

`foodItemsList[i]` has the error of

> ArrayType expected, instead found
>   javafx.collections.ObservableList

This is my code:

```
menu.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( e -> {
        flowPane.getChildren().clear();

        for (Integer i : menu.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices()) {
            flowPane.getChildren().add(foodPics[i]);
        }
    });

    // ### This just displays the current value and the value I last selected, if I selected 3+ values,
    // the last 2 are the only ones that show.
    menu.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            item1.setText(newValue);
            item2.setText(oldValue);
        }
    });

    menu.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( e -> {
        flowPane.getChildren().clear();
        for (String i : menu.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()) {
            vBox.getChildren().add(foodItemsList[i]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You have three listeners on the selection; when the selection changes they will all be executed, but in an undetermined order. Two of those listeners clear the flow pane... so if the labels are added first, the listener that adds the image views will clear all the labels that were just added. You probably want to combine the first and third listeners into a single listener.

Comment: Ah, the 3rd listener should clear vBox, not FlowPane, my mistake. I've tried combining it, but the problem is adding the text, I think there's a syntax error, but I'm not familiar enough with JavaFX to know what it is because when I try to add from this line:             vBox.getChildren().add(foodItemsList[i]); "footItemsList[i] has the error of "ArrayType expected, instead found javafx.collections.ObservableList<String>"

Comment: OK, so that is fairly self-explanatory, isn't it? You can't access elements of a list using array syntax. (Also, you can't add `String`s to a `VBox`.)

Comment: So should I not be doing a for each loop then? Or if I am supposed to, it should be an integer accessing the indices? I thought following the same syntax as the ImageView would do the trick. Should I be trying to access it as a list? Should I have a .setText() method instead of the .add()?

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly